# given p3, p4 , m , how to find p1 and p2

Tags: math, geometry, coordinates

given p3 p4 and m (midpoint of p1 and p2) , how do i find p1 and p2, please help.

```
             p1(x1,y1)        m(xmid,ymid)     p2(x2,y2)
               ---------------------------------
               |                               |
               |                               |
               |                               |
               |                               |
               |                               |
               |                               |
               |                               |
               ---------------------------------
              p3(x3,y3)                        p4(x4,y4)
```

Comment: Is this meant to be an axis-aligned rectangle?

Comment: No , y1 is not equal to y2 , and y3 is not equal to y4 , which mean rectangle can be in any direction

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how *you* tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us *exactly* what the result was and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you really need to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the midpoint of `p3` and `p4`. The difference to `m` will be the rectangle's missing side:

```
m34x = 0.5 * (x3 + x4)
m34y = 0.5 * (y3 + y4)
dx = xmid - m34x
dy = ymid - m34y

x1 = x3 + dx
y1 = y3 + dy
x2 = x4 + dx
y2 = y4 + dy
```